# Node.js + Express.js + Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

Doesn't work anyway, I really tried so many different ways but nothing works..
I want establish a realtime connection with socket.io to monitor a redis db to get every new added item on a list. 
Any ideas ?

app.js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var crawler = require('crawler.js');


var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
//app.use(express.errorHandler());
}
 app.get('/rootaccess',function(req, res){
res.render('crawlercontrol');
});
app.get('/crawler/monitor',function(req, res){
res.render('monitor');
});
app.get('/crawler/start',function(req,res){
crawler.start(res);
});

app.get('/crawler/stop',function(req,res){
crawler.stop(res);
});


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(3111));

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('hei socket.io');
    socket.emit('message', { message: 'welcome to the chat' });
    socket.on('send', function (data) {
        io.sockets.emit('message', data);
    });
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ROOT Monitor</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="/js/libs/modernizr.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div id="monitor">
    Monitor
</div>
</body>
<script src="/js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/js/libs/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js' />
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3111');
    socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    });
</script>
</script>
</html>
```

At this moment the only Error which appears is that socket.io doesn't provide the socket.io.js for the client..

Comment: Where do you get this error?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is it or not; it's just a hunch. In `app.js` you tell the express app to listen on the assigned port in the `app` object:

```
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), ...
```

But then when you create `io`, you call `app.listen()` again within the `listen` method of the object `require` returns.

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(3111));
```

My hunch is that perhaps you are forcing the `app` server to  listen twice which may be causing the issue, again just a hunch. If I am wrong tell me. If you really want to listen on port 3111, you could try this:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3111);
```

See if that gets you anywhere.